# Haskell - show function cuts the first element zero from the Int-Value - how to avoid it?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following exercise:

I need do write a function which checks if the entered `Int`-value is `>= 4`  and `<= 6` and does not start with `0`. Then the function should give back a `True`.

This is the function I have to implement: (`pinCheck :: Int -> Bool` is given)

```hs
pinCheck :: Int -> Bool 
pinCheck x 
    | (( last (ab)) /= '0' ) && len <= 6 && len >= 4 = True
    | otherwise = False
    where 
    len = length (digs x) 
    ab = reverse (show x)

digs :: Integral x => x -> [x]
digs 0 = []
digs x = digs (x `div`10) ++ [x `mod` 10]
```

I have to check a testcase with the given `Int`-value `0323`. It has to give out *false*, but it gives out *true*.

I wanted to convert the `Int` to a `String` and then check with head if the first value is `/= 0`. But while converting, it cuts off the `0` automatically.
I didn't know that the `show` function did that, so I wanted first to reverse the converted string and then check the last element if it is `/= 0` but...

Now my question: Is it with my fundamental program code possible to solve this problem?

Comment: just an observation (don't want to interrupt your conversation with Daniel): the test case `0323` even when you type it as an `Int` should return false just because `323` does not have 4 digits (just `pinCheck x = x >= 1000 && x <= 999999` should be enough for that). Can you maybe add other test-cases (if you where given any more)? I think you just did not understand the task correctly

Comment: yes you are right, sorry. pinCheck 123 ~?= False,
        pinCheck 1234 ~?= True,
        pinCheck 0167 ~?= False,
        pinCheck 167927 ~?= True,
        pinCheck 067927 ~?= False  ; but the problem is the same, with the last test...only this is given to me to implement the function: pinCheck :: Int -> Bool

Comment: as Daniel said if without a further constraint this test-case is impossible to do (assuming `pinCheck 67927 == True`  should hold)

Comment: so also when I create a function for the signature listMake Int -> [Int], with the test case listMake 2613 ~?= [2,6,1,3], I cant solve this pinCheck, right?

Comment: I think those two are unrelated - the issue here is either the test cases & description or the test-cases and signature - `Int` beginning with `0` is the issue here - but Daniel discussed this already - sorry I cannot help either - I'd suggest talking with your Prof. or TA

Comment: lol i am soo.... i misunderstood this function. it has to be only either 4 chars long or 6 chars. not >= 4 and <= 6... will post the solution later.

Comment: so I only need to check the length if 4 or 6 for true...

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not possible. If you want to preserve presentational details about the number, have `pinCheck` take a `String` instead of an `Int`.

Comment: This is crazy... this exercice was given to us students... so there is absolutely NO WAY to get a solution with the given signature? There are also no predefined functions in the haskell package?

Comment: @wantstothinkandgehtthesolution With the constraints given, no, it is not possible. An `Int` does not "remember" how you typed it in -- only its value. `0323`, `323`, `0o503`, and `0x143` all represent the same in-memory sequence of bits. If there are extra constraints -- e.g. perhaps you know the number is always supposed to be rendered as having 4 digits -- then perhaps the answer would change.

Comment: So, the first exerice was to implement a function, which makes a list of a string. I solved this with the digs function. And in the second exercice we had to implement the function pinCheck. And they gave us the tipp, that the first function could help us for the second. So I used digs again in pinCheck... But maybe there is another way to solve exercice 1/to use another function... there are more testcases, some with less than 4 numbers, some which start with 0, and some with more than 4 numbers...

Comment: @wantstothinkandgehtthesolution Okay, well, if using `digs` in your implementation for the first part makes the rest of the problem impossible, I guess the obvious suggestion is not to use `digs` in your implementation for the first part.

Comment: Mhhh, didnt know how to solve it in another way... But I think maybe it makes no difference because the signature from pinCheck still is from Int to Bool...

Comment: @wantstothinkandgehtthesolution I encourage you to try the following exercise. Take out your phone, and set a five minute timer. (Don't try to judge yourself when five minutes are up; you'll stop early. That isn't weakness, just the human condition.) Then close your eyes and think about the problem in as many different ways as you can. Don't generate solutions yet, just think of the problem. (If a solution does pop into your mind, say, "neat!", write it down, then close your eyes and resume thinking.) I think you will like your results; I always do.

Comment: I did and I think I can do for the first exercice the following: first convert the int into a string with show. And then with pattern matching, each element add to an empty list and split with ",". Because the first function have to do this: from 1234 to ["1", "2", "3", "4"]. But for example my idea will work, then I do not know how it woult help me, because  I would get the same result? (lol or maybe not, because I will not divide through 10?